# how to compare two database's table get fields different mysql

Tags: mysql

situation is like

DB:A , Table:member
pk , id , name , birthday , phone , cell , address

DB:B , Table:member
pd , id , name , birthday

wants to get the difference with only

> "field"

in this situation hope it would show :

> phone , cell , address

```
SELECT *
FROM `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.`COLUMNS` 
WHERE `TABLE_SCHEMA` = 'db_name' 
    AND `TABLE_NAME`='table_name';
```

I tried this but only show all column.
Thanks

Comment: Refer this : https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2779/ways-to-compare-and-find-differences-for-sql-server-tables-and-data/

Answer (score 0):

Dump both the tables in sql file and apply

```
diff table1.sql table1.sql
```